# Set Thread priority with console.readline? c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-priority

I'm wondering if you can change the priority of a thread by letting the user enter a string (Lowest, BelowNormal etc)? As far as I know, the "ThreadPriority" is an enum but I don't know how to do it.

```
thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
```

How can I change the BelowNormal to something the user enter (ReadLine)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it as simple as sending it a number corresponding to the value of the enum priorities?

Comment: Try to parse it with Enum.Parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
thread.Priority = (ThreadPriority)Enum.Parse(typeof(ThreadPriority), Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the fast reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx), example uses overload method with `ignoreCase`:

```
thread.Priority = (ThreadPriority)Enum.Parse(typeof(ThreadPriority), 
                                      "belownormal", true);
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the fast reply!

Answer (score -2):

You could parse the string and do a conditional

```
string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
if (userinput.Contains("BelowNormal"))
{
    thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the fast reply!

Comment: Thx, it's been forever since ive used the console

Comment: So, what if I type `NotBelowNormal`?

Comment: Then simply do: if (userinput.Contains("BelowNormal") && !userinput.Contains("NotBelowNormal")) { }